# Using local Julia modules in Pluto

Tags: julia, pluto.jl

What is the correct way to import local modules in Pluto v0.18.0 notebooks with Julia 1.7.2?
The `using` keyword adds exported members to the main namespace in Julia. Given a sample module, in `foo.jl`,

```
module Foo
    export bar
    function bar()
        return "baz"
    end
end
```

The following code cell works in a Pluto Notebook:

```
# "baz"
begin
    include("./foo.jl")
    using .Foo
    bar()
end
```

However, if I attempt to call `bar` from another cell, I get the following error:

```
# UndefVarError: bar not defined
bar()
```

Though I notice that `Foo.bar()` does work.

How do I add my own modules in a way that I get access to their exported members directly in the notebook's namespace?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/pluto-vs-ijulia-including-a-local-module/64866/3)?

Comment: Yes, it says "workspaceN" not defined for any N I try. I did find something on a discussion linked from there, which might be a good solution. Posting that as the answer, as  that's what I think I'll go with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [discussion](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl/issues/115#issuecomment-661722426) gives a possible solution. It describes a better way of getting the module reference than what I have in my question.

If the module is not the last definition in the file, the `import` function has to be redefined. A suggested name is to have a variant called "`ingredients`"

```
#ingredients (generic function with 1 method)
function ingredients(path::String)
    # this is from the Julia source code (evalfile in base/loading.jl)
    # but with the modification that it returns the module instead of the last object
    name = Symbol(basename(path))
    m = Module(name)
    Core.eval(m,
        Expr(:toplevel,
             :(eval(x) = $(Expr(:core, :eval))($name, x)),
             :(include(x) = $(Expr(:top, :include))($name, x)),
             :(include(mapexpr::Function, x) = $(Expr(:top, :include))(mapexpr, $name, x)),
             :(include($path))))
    m
end
```

Then the module can be loaded in like so (I don't know the reason why I have to say `ingredients().Foo`)

```
#Main.Foo.jl.Foo
Foo = ingredients("My Library/Foo.jl").Foo
```

and then with the module reference, you have to manually bring all exported variables into the global scope:

```
#bar = bar (generic function with 1 method)
bar = Foo.bar
```